# How do I add a new "bullet" style to the list of frequently used bullets in powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Powerpoint conveniently gives me a list of default bullet styles to use, but I want to add another - the dash ("-").

How can I do this?

Thanks!
/YGA[image]

Answer (score 2):

From PowerPoint Help:

There are a few things you can't do with lists in PowerPoint that you can in other Office programs, such as Word. For example, PowerPoint does not support:

Decimal numbered lists (1.1, 1.2, etc.).

Defining new number formats (you must choose from the default set of styles offered on the Numbered tab in the Bullets and Numbering dialog box).

Applying bold, italic, or underline formatting to bullets or numbers (any formatting will be applied to the entire selected line or list).

Nested lists (you can press Tab or click Increase Indent Increase Indent button to create the same effect, but a new indented bullet or number style is not set automatically by PowerPoint).

Answer (score 1):

1. Click *"Bullets and Numbering..."*
2. Click *"Customize..."*
   [image: screenshot]
3. Click on the symbol you want to use (e.g. hyphen)
   [image: screenshot]
4. Click *"Okay"* two times
5. It should look something like this:
   [image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes but that doesn't make it permanently in the menu.

Comment: @YGA Sorry, I've been looking through the menus, and I don't think that is possible. However, you could just select some text that has the custom bullet style, put it in the clipboard, and then paste it where you need it and just change the text. The bullet style will still be the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can "add" another, but you can Customize existing one. Click on Bullets and Numbering - Choose one you hardly ever use and Customize to your liking.

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to what steps that involves? Thanks!

Comment: @YGA Sorry looks like cloudcoder2000 method is the expansion of mine (with screenshots and everything) and yes I don't see how to set the custom one as the default.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to have a new default bullet style:

1. Choose View>Slide Master
2. Click on the text placeholder of your default slide
3. Click "Bullets and Numbering..."
4. Click "Customize..."
5. Select the right bullet style
6. Save and exit the Slide Master

It works... **but** a default new slide will appear with bullets.